# Enhancement in styling of user interface

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a UI which displays 7-8 columns on one page. Now i need to incorporate either a ">>" symbol or "More Option" on the right side to make it look less clumsy... The view is coded in Html. Please let me know how to style it?

Comment: Ask specific question. What have you done (partial html)? Have you searched web for similar questions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are different ways, first of all you could use JQuery and use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or html. You could make it new with [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/).

But why don't you simply change the html view?

Comment: As you were suggesting earlier,please let me know how to incorporate sorting by just changing the html view?